# Problems disabling socks5 proxy | tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, socks, transparent-proxy

I was trying to create a PHP application that utilizes a local socks5 proxy to anonymize my IP address on each curl request. I couldn't successfully get the application to use a socks5 proxy. But in doing all that I have found that now some applications no longer connect to the internet, such as wget, curl and git.

wget responds with:

`Error parsing proxy URL socks5://127.0.0.1:8080: Unsupported scheme ‘socks5’.`

curl responds with

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused`

git responds with

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jamiejackherer/idealer/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused`

I dont know how to disable the socks5 proxy from listening, I even tried uninstalling tor and tor browser bundle but it seems something else is keeping the listener open but I don't know what or even how to check. I have searched online for 2 days non-stop but I can't find anything. I am afraid that I will start messing my system up if I change too much configuration.

Any idea's on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is tor running? If not...what does this have to do with Tor at all?

Comment: Whether tor is running or not the problem persists.. I tried proxy-ing my application with both tor (built from source) or tor browser bundle running, I then removed all tor files (my build and the browser bundle). I am still unsure exactly how i got it to  work

Comment: So this isn't related to Tor?

Comment: the problem only appeared after editing my torrc files, so the problem is no longer due to tor but started because of tor.. any other ideas?

Comment: If Tor isn't running? No. You probably want to ask a more general server support community about server administration?

Comment: what does tor do to any ip routes after setting up tor as a local proxy?

Comment: Nothing at all.

Comment: So how does it reroute http traffic from socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80, I think my problem is that when using tor as a proxy it has changed some configuration somewhere, even Pythons requests module gives an error - `<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSConnection` for normal requests.. it has seemingly broken my internal DNS to route everything to a socks5:// protocol even when tor is not running

Comment: It doesn't automatically reroute traffic, you need to configure things to use Tor. It only affects itself and Tor Browser. You've changed a setting somewhere and I have no idea where or why, possibly some global environment variable or a setting in your desktop environment (gnome, kde, whatever).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the purpose of this questions seems to commit illegal activities (see comments).

Comment: @JensKubieziel as i stated clearly in the comments, hacking someones account other than my own is illegal, which means im not hacking accounts, im merely educating myself on facebooks security measures in order to better my understanding of web security! facebook has some of the best security around today - something with which we could all take a leaf from that book!! And on top of that... what a DICK you are sir!! you are actually very childish !! you wish to close a question which has been resolved by myself 8 days ago!! Again I see this site is nothing but a sad state of affairs !! PRICK!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have port 8080 for your Socks5 - it's 9050 in Tor and 1080 or 3128 by default in most of apps. Second - Tor does **not** touch a packets outside the ones coming to his ports. You have added some environmental variables I think. For `wget` there's **no** socks proxy support, see [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html?) for variable names and I think the problem is that you have used polipo or privoxy to channel HTTP+HTTPS requests to SOCKS ones. I do recommend you to use polipo, but it's my personal preference. You bind it to 8080 - and use http schema for request. Also check your user's, root's and global(in /etc folder) bash shell profiles - some guides are also pointing to making aliases for curl there. A good environment vars overvuew can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/proxy_settings) but the proxy vars names are standard and they are `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `frp_proxy`, `rsync_proxy`, `socks_proxy` and for exclusions `no_proxy`. Remember that due to the early times these variables must be *duplicated in uppercase*, i.e. if you want to set http_proxy - you also set the same value for HTTP_PROXY, just to be fail-safe. For curl also keep in mind that over Tor **not** `socks5://` but `socks5h://` must be used - it will force name resolution on proxy side, according to the official [docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). Curl can also be configured via it's [config file](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline-configfile.html) where is in key=value format options are specified, so take a look there too.

Comment: Ok I appreciate your input but firstly - I do NOT and have never set my SOCKSPort to 8080! And the defaults do vary between either 9050 or 9150 .. :/ I don't use defaults as it poses risks.. I changed my SOCKSPort and ControlPort as soon i started reading about using a socks proxy! Also I haven't installed polipo or privoxy. You were right on one thing though.. I had set some env vars in my .bashrc that I had forgotten about and am annoyed that I never even needed them setting anyway! I have since learnt to set two env vars `proxyOn` and `proxyOff`. You have provided some good info though TY!

Comment: you're welcome! in my opinion - drop wget and adopt curl, it's socks5h schema is safe, no leaks there. To avoid env vars avalanche - especially set system-wide - reboot your machine with fixed shell profiles, it will wipe the remaining traces entirely from running config

Comment: I will show my gratitude by marking your answer as the correct one as it did offer some good info and you were right in the env vars part. Thanks and also.. with curl I learnt to use `curl --socks5-hostname <proxy_ip>:<proxy_port> <url>`

Comment: curl has it's text config file - put it there! even more tricks: in SocksPort flags make isolation by-user-login, and add username auth in socks - it will run separate curl instances in separate streams in Tor, it's usally faster. Also once set in text config - you don't need to type all the stuff in every place you use curl command

Comment: --socks5-hostname is also a working flag, but in some time it was introduced as a built-in drop-in with socks5**h**:// schema - just to make things simple

Comment: And I really do love love wget over curl, its a shame the socks support is not in place! I am actually not even using my socks proxy for use with wget or curl, just found they didnt work after setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` env vars.. Im using a socks proxy for a php application that brute forces facebook login, I have a lot to learn in regards to tor exiting from particular geoip locations depending on the users location.. do you have any good links to go reading/learning?

Comment: I've found https://github.com/clue/php-socks which seems to be doing a really good job as a controller for socks proxying with php

Comment: SOCKS has been around for decades and it's very well documented, so I'm not surprised

Comment: facebook login brute force is illegal unless you're auditing them and/or have an agreement that allows you to do so, you know? `Exiting from` = adding two lines in your torrc: `StrictNodes 1` and `ExitNodes <a comma separated list`. Try torrc manual, it's very well documented

Comment: cheers, brute forcing someone else's account is illegal! And tbh I dont really care, Facebook are a horrible entity that give your details to certain agencies and such, they will even grant access to the highest bidder! I dont like them and personally feel they deserve all they get handed to them! :)